# how to get the world position of cursor which is attached to camera in aframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, aframe, webvr

i want to get the world location of cursor to help me create hotspots for 360 tour for that i have created a component that returns the position of cursor. The component is working fine but it returns the relative position of cursor so what should i do to get the world position of cursor

[link to glich project](https://glitch.com/~courageous-toaster)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these `THREE.js` methods:

```
// set a vector from the cursors matrix world
vec3.setFromMatrixPosition(cursorEl.object3D.matrixWorld);

// fill a vector using the getWorldPosition
cursorEl.object3D.getWorldPosition(vec3)
```

Check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/480myw3g/32/).

---

### Using it within a custom component.

Having a setup like this

```
<a-camera>
   <a-cursor my-component></a-cursor>
</a-camera>
```

You could have a component like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("my-component", {
   init: function() {
       this.vec = new THREE.Vector3()
   },
   tick: function() {
       this.vec.setFromMatrixPosition(this.el.object3D.matrixWorld);
       // do something with this.vec
   }
})
```